# C - Find the size of structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I was asked this as interview question. Couldn't answer.

> Write a C program to find size of structure without using the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: yes - lots of we does

Comment: I think your interviewer is a bit goofy and you should be skeptical about working there.  What does this accomplish?

Comment: isn't it technically possible for the size of a struct to be smaller than the size it takes up in an array?

Comment: @Martin ...I don't get it. :)

Comment: @muntoo - orig question just asked "does anyone knows how"

Comment: @Bwmat: Nope, it's not. That's the definition of the size.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
struct  XYZ{
    int x;
    float y;
    char z;
};

int main(){
    struct XYZ arr[2];
    int sz = (char*)&arr[1] - (char*)&arr[0];
    printf("%d",sz);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An array of one element (or a single object) is sufficient, since it is legal to compute the address one-past-the-end of an array.

Comment: @JorgeIsraelPeña: it just takes the difference between the memory address(the pointer) of the first element in the array and the address of the second element.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach. <strike>It also isn't completely defined but will still work on most systems.</strike>

```
typedef struct{
    //  stuff
} mystruct;

int main(){
    mystruct x;
    mystruct *p = &x;

    int size = (char*)(p + 1) - (char*)p;
    printf("Size = %d\n",size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What part of this program do you think "isn't completely defined"?

Comment: I take that back. I was under the impression that doing arithmetic after typecasts was undefined.

Comment: You should use `size_t` but otherwise this is pretty completely defined.

Comment: @Chris: I thought about that too, but I wasn't sure of the `printf()` code needed to print a `size_t`.

Comment: @Mystical - `"%zu"` was added to C99 I believe, but `%lu` will "probably work" and `"%llu"` with a cast is "good enough" if you need C89 compatability.

Comment: @Chris: except that `long long` (and `"%llu"`) weren't required by C89 :-)

Comment: @Chris: `%llu` does not even exist in C89. `%lu` with a cast to `unsigned long` is probably ok; it's the best you can do for C89.

Comment: @Mystical: `p` is not needed; just replace all instances of `p` with `&x`.

Comment: @pmg, @R.. - It should give you a hint of how little I was thinking about that when I say that I considered recommending `intmax_t`. My B.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach.... no need to create any instance of structure.

```
struct  XYZ{
    int x;
    float y;
    char z;
};

int main(){
    int sz = (int) (((struct XYZ *)0) + 1);
    printf("%d",sz);
    return 0;
}
```

How does it work?

```
((struct XYZ *)0) + 1 = zero + size of structure
                      = size of structure
```

Comment: aesthetically said !

Answer (score 0):

Here's two macro versions for the two forms of `sizeof` (takes a type vs. takes a variable) that you can use for all the code you'll never write where you aren't allowed to use `sizeof`:

```
#define type_sizeof(t) (size_t)((char *)((t *)1024 + 1) - (char *)((t *)1024))
#define var_sizeof(v)  (size_t)((char *)(&(v) + 1) - (char *)&(v))
```

Perhaps with some deep magic you can combine the two into a single macro that will almost serve as a drop-in replacement in all this `sizeof`-less code. (Too bad you can't fix the multiple-evaluation bugs.)

Answer (score 0):

For people that like C macro style coding, here is my take on this:

```
#define SIZE_OF_STRUCT(mystruct)     \
   ({ struct nested_##mystruct {     \
         struct mystruct s;          \
         char end[0];                \
      } __attribute__((packed)) var; \
      var.end - (char *)&var; })

void main()
{
   struct mystruct {
      int c;
   };

   printf("size %d\n", SIZE_OF_STRUCT(mystruct));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ABC
{
    int a, b[3];
    int c;
    float d;
    char e, f[2];
};
int main()
{
    struct ABC *ptr=(struct ABC *)0;
    clrscr();
    ptr++;
    printf("Size of structure is: %d",ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
struct  ABC

{

int a;

float b;

char c;

};


void main()
{

struct ABC *ptr=(struct ABC *)0;

ptr++;

printf("Size of structure is: %d",*ptr);

}
```